# Web Scraper: Limit to Requests Per Minute/Hour on Single Domain?

Tags: python, http, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm working with a librarian to re-structure his organization's digital photography archive.

I've built a Python robot with [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to pull about 7000 poorly structured and mildy incorrect/incomplete documents from a collection.  The data will be formatted for a spreadsheet he can use to correct it.  Right now I'm guesstimating 7500 HTTP requests total to build the search dictionary and then harvest the data, not counting mistakes and do-overs in my code, and then many more as the project progresses.

I assume there's some sort of built-in limit to how quickly I can make these requests, and even if there's not I'll give my robot delays to behave politely with the over-burdened web server(s).  My question (admittedly impossible to answer with complete accuracy), is **about how quickly can I make HTTP requests before encountering a built-in rate limit?**

I would prefer not to publish the URL for the domain we're scraping, but if it's relevant I'll ask my friend if it's okay to share.

Note: I realize this is *not* the best way to solve our problem (re-structuring/organizing the database) but we're building a proof-of-concept to convince the higher-ups to trust my friend with a copy of the database, from which he'll navigate the bureaucracy necessary to allow me to work directly with the data.

They've also given us the API for an ATOM feed, but it requires a keyword to search and seems useless for the task of stepping through every photograph in a particular collection.

Comment: I suggest you make one request per second and run it over night or over the weekend. You should be save then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in rate limit for HTTP.  Most common web servers are not configured out of the box to rate limit.  If rate limiting is in place, it will almost certainly have been put there by the administrators of the website and you'd have to ask them what they've configured.

Some search engines respect a non-standard extension to robots.txt that suggests a rate limit, so check for `Crawl-delay` in `robots.txt`.

HTTP does have a *concurrent connection* limit of two connections, but browsers have already started ignoring that and efforts are underway to revise that part of the standard as it is quite outdated.

Comment: robots.txt (= PERFECT!  "Crawl-delay: 10" -- Do I assume that means 10 seconds?