# Python mechanize returns HTTP 429 error

Tags: python, http, mechanize, http-status-code-429

I am trying to do an automated task via python through the `mechanize` module:

1. Enter the keyword in a web form, submit the form.
2. Look for a specific element in the response.

This works one-time. Now, I repeat this task for a list of keywords.

And am getting HTTP Error 429 (Too many requests).

I tried the following to workaround this:

1. Adding custom headers (I noted them down specifically for that very website by using a proxy ) so that it looks a legit browser request .

   ```
   br=mechanize.Browser()
   br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')]
   br.addheaders = [('Connection', 'keep-alive')]
   br.addheaders = [('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')]
   br.addheaders = [('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests','1')]
   br.addheaders = [('Accept-Encoding',' gzip, deflate, sdch')]
   br.addheaders = [('Accept-Language','en-US,en;q=0.8')]`
   ```
2. Since the blocked response was coming for every 5th request , I tried sleeping for 20 sec after 5 requests .

Neither of the two methods worked.

Comment: just realised it takes tuple                                                               br.addheaders = [('user-agent', '   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3'),
('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773567/web-scraper-limit-to-requests-per-minute-hour-on-single-domain <- this may show the actual request limit set forth by the site's administrator.

Comment: Getting a new error now .                                                                                 mechanize FormNotFoundError . On removing the header i get proper result . But again the limit problem .

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the rate of your requests to conform to what the server's configuration permits. ([Web Scraper: Limit to Requests Per Minute/Hour on Single Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773567/web-scraper-limit-to-requests-per-minute-hour-on-single-domain) may show the permitted rate)

`mechanize` uses a heavily-patched version of `urllib2` (`Lib/site-packages/mechanize/_urllib2.py`) for network operations, and its `Browser` class is a descendant of its `_urllib2_fork.OpenerDirector`.

So, the simplest method to patch its logic seems to add a `handler` to your `Browser` object

- with `default_open` and appropriate `handler_order` to place it before everyone (lower is higher priority).
- that would stall until the request is eligible with e.g. a [Token bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) or [Leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) algorithm e.g. as implemented in [Throttling with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456649/throttling-with-urllib2/456668#456668) . Note that a bucket should probably be per-domain or per-IP.
- and finally `return None` to push the request to the following handlers

Since this is a common need, you should probably publish your implementation as an installable package.